# Cardinality of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

We know that the cardinality of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive Lebesgue measure is the continuum. What can we say about the cardinality of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive outer measure?

Comment: has to be that of the continuum too

Comment: @OliverDiaz Not necessrily. It's possible that $2^{\aleph_0}\gt\aleph_1$ and there are non-measurable sets of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: In the real line, if you take the continuum hypothesis, subsets of $\mathbb{R}$  of positive outer measure are uncountable and hence f cordiality $\mathcal{c}$.

Comment: @Oliver: Nowhere here we are assuming CH, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality is independent of the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Given the ideal $\mathcal N$ of Lebesgue null sets, we call the least cardinality of a subset of $\Bbb R$ that is not Lebesgue null (i.e. has positive outer measure) the *uniformity number* of $\mathcal N$, or $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal N)$.

This is one of the cardinal characteristics featured in [Cichoń's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram), and as such its cardinality has been extensively studied. Assuming that we have a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then the method of forcing can be used to prove the existence of models where $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal N)<2^{\aleph_0}$. Conversely, it can also be shown to be consistent that $\aleph_1<\mathrm{non}(\mathcal N)=2^{\aleph_0}$.

In other words, it is relatively consistent to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there are sets of positive outer measure of cardinality less than the continuum, but it is also relatively consistent that no such sets exist, even when the continuum hypothesis does not hold.